# Using $_GET params in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, parameters, get

I am not a backend developer but I would like to change something in my site.

So I have incoming links like this.
https://four44.com/abc?user=123&design=onetwothree

I want to see the data for

1. user
2. design
3. IP address
   in WP database

So what im trying to achieve is, would wordpress be able to store this in database? I really have no idea on how to start as well with this. Or is there any wordpress plugin that can make this easier for me?

A step by step would be great!

Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: Where are the incoming links coming from? Are they external?

Comment: Yes they are external links from another source.

Answer (score 1):

To get this just use:

```
//param user from query (123)
$user = $_GET['user'];

//param design from query (onetwothree)
$design = $_GET['design'];

//client ip address (95.42.78.250) example
$clientIpAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Comment: hi, sorry for asking as I am a total newbie, but where do i put this code at?

Comment: where ever you receive these requests or in case of wordpress you can create method in functions.php where if requested page is whatever, you get this data ... Your question is too broad.

Comment: Thank you for replying Angel. In my case of wordpress, I will get this Parameters in all the blog posts that I have. Is there an all ecompassing place to put this code, so that all blog posts will record the Parameters? Once again, I am truly sorry as I am not really good in the backend.